# Print Sales Invoice Report into PDF AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to save a Sales Invoice PDF automatically when the user creates an invoice. When the user clicks the create button, the invoice will be created and, at the same time, it will be save as a PDF in a path. The problem I'm facing is that the PDF is saved in blank and whenever I execute the code, AX stops working. This is what I have until now:

```
public void savePDFInServer(CustInvoiceJour custInvoiceJour, TaxTypeDocumentId taxTypeDocumentId, InvoiceDate invoiceDate)
{
PrintMgmtReportFormatName printMgmtReportFormatName;
SRSPrintDestinationSettings     settings;
SrsReportRunController          controller = new SrsReportRunController();
PurchPurchaseOrderContract  rdpContract = new PurchPurchaseOrderContract();
SalesInvoiceContract    salesInvoiceContract = new SalesInvoiceContract();

controller.parmReportName(printMgmtReportFormatName);
controller.parmExecutionMode(SysOperationExecutionMode::Synchronous);

rdpContract.parmRecordId(custInvoiceJour.RecId);
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(rdpContract);

salesInvoiceContract.parmRecordId(custInvoiceJour.RecId); 
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(salesInvoiceContract);
salesInvoiceContract.parmCountryRegionISOCode(SysCountryRegionCode::countryInfo());

settings = controller.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings();
settings.printMediumType(SRSPrintMediumType::File);
settings.fileFormat(SRSReportFileFormat::PDF);
settings.overwriteFile(true);
settings.fileName(@'C:\Users\spineda\Desktop\Prueba.pdf');

controller.parmShowDialog(false);
controller.startOperation();
}
```

Comment: At first glance...why are you using `PurchPurchaseOrderContract` for what appears to be a  sales invoice?

Comment: @AlexKwitny I'm really not sure, I was following a code that I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the code, I realized that the problem was that the record was not saved in the table and when it tried to save the pdf, the record was not commited. What I did is that I made sure that the record was saved in the table and then I generated the pdf.